# Working of Date[]

Tags: syntax, date-and-time

`Date[]` returns the current date of local system, `Date[1]` returns {2012, 11, 15, 17, 41, 0.3161629}, `Date[2]` returns {2012, 11, 15, 18, 41, 0.3161629}, and `Date[3]` returns {2012, 11, 15, 18, 41, 0.3161629} and so on and why?
Also, I tried this code

```
    a = DateList[] (*line 1*)
    a = a + {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0} (*Line 2*)
```

After executing Line 2 for a few more times I get {2012, 11, 15, 25, 41, 0.3161629}. How can I fix this as I want to use increment time by 1 hour or 30 min in a `For` loop

Comment: `Date[]` is deprecated; any reason why you need to use it instead of `DateList[]`?

Comment: From the `Date` documentation "`Date` has been superseded by `DateList` since Version 6.0." and it says first argument is timezone, i.e. how many hours away from GMT. I recommend using DateList

Comment: Can i use date as loop counter

Comment: And use `DatePlus` when adding to a date (see `DateDifference` too)

Comment: Yeah i got it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`Date` is deprecated.  According to the Mathematica 5 documentation, `Date[z]` returns the time in time zone `z`.

You probably want to use `DateList` to accomplish the kinds of things you are describing.  The following will add an hour and a half to the current date:

```
date = DateList[]
DatePlus[date, 3/48]

(* Out:
  {2012, 11, 15, 12, 7, 3.572165}
  {2012, 11, 15, 13, 37, 3.572}
*)
```

This works because `DatePlus[date, n]` adds `n` days to date and $1.5$ hours is $3/48$ of a day. There's probably a better way to specify the units; you could consult the `DatePlus` documentation to find out.